# Passing req.session to route

Tags: node.js, express, session

I'm trying to make login session in nodejs,

My app.js

```
app.post('/login', async(req, res) => {
const { login, password } = req.body


const admin = await register.findOne({ where: { login } })
if (await bcrypt.compare(password, admin.password)) {

    req.session.admin = true

    res.render('adminPage', { session:req.session.admin }) <---- this not working
} else {
    res.send("Wrong password...")
}
})
```

I'm trying to pass " req.session.admin" to my route to make some kind of authentication

My routes/adminPage.js

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
router.get('/', (req, res) => {

    //request.session.admin always giving me "undefined"
try { if (request.session.admin == true) res.render('adminPage') } catch {
    res.send("You have to log in...")
}


})
module.exports = router
```

Is it possible to do or am I stupid?

Comment: You need to use some kind of cookie or other mechanism to store the session info on the client side after a login, then use some middleware to retrieve the session on each request. Maybe follow some kind of guide on session handling in express.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just initializing a key called `session` in you request object then indeed your data is being lost after sending the response. I'd go for a third-party solution which persists and rehydrates the data, manages expiration date, so on... Eg: [Express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session)

Also, I would move my logic to check "whether the user is logged in" to a [middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) so I could reuse that code and have it separeted from the main concern of the endpoint.